# How do I update a section of a Bytes/BytesMut?

Tags: rust, buffer

I have a fixed size buffer in a `Bytes` struct, and I want to copy some data over the middle of it.

The only thing I can see at the moment would be to take a slice of the beginning, add what I want, and add the slice at the end, but I'm sure this will result in a large copy or two that I want to avoid, I simply need to update the middle of the buffer. Is there a simple way of doing that without using `unsafe`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *don't* mutate `Bytes`. The entire purpose of the struct is to represent a reference-counted immutable view of data. You will need to copy the data in some fashion. Perhaps you create a `Vec<u8>` or `BytesMut` from the data.

`BytesMut` implements `AsMut<[u8]>`, `BorrowMut<[u8]>` and `DerefMut`, so you can use any existing technique for modifying slices in-place. For example:

```
use bytes::BytesMut; // 0.5.4

fn main() {
    let mut b = BytesMut::new();
    b.extend_from_slice(b"a good time");

    let middle = &mut b[2..][..4];
    middle.copy_from_slice(b"cool");

    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&b));
}
```

See also:

- [How to idiomatically copy a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219231/155423)
- [How do you copy between arrays of different sizes in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25225346/155423)
- [How can I write data from a slice to the same slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39604042/155423)
- [How to operate on 2 mutable slices of a Rust array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36244762/155423)
- [How do I create two new mutable slices from one slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24872634/155423)

> without using `unsafe`

**Do not use `unsafe` for this problem**. You *will* cause undefined behavior.

Comment: okay... that's basically what I was looking for thanks, and I know I can't mutate a Bytes, but I'm also not seeing how to gain mutability from a Bytes. And yes, I don't want to use unsafe.

Comment: @stu There is `unsafe` and then there is `unsafe`. I mean, there are situations where you *may* use `unsafe`, even though you might not want to, and there are situations where what you want is impossible within the rules of the language and you *must not* use `unsafe` to break them. This is the second kind of situation. If you have a `Bytes`, you cannot mutate it, full stop. You must go back to where the code is giving you the `Bytes` and somehow convince it to give you a `BytesMut` instead.